# Why decimal fields accept letter in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I was trying some queries on a table and I noticed that it is possible in a decimal field to pass letters in where clause getting all the results

```
CREATE TABLE materials (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
description VARCHAR(255),
cost DECIMAL(19 , 4 ) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO materials(description,cost)
VALUES('Bicycle', 500.34),('Seat',10.23),('Break',5.21);
```

SELECT

```
select cost from materials WHERE cost > 'a';
```

RESULT

```
|   cost |
|--------|
| 500.34 |
|  10.23 |
|   5.21 |
```

How can I get results only if I use numbers in the clause where with decimal?

Thank you

Comment: As a demonstration of what MySQL is doing with the string try this ...  `SELECT 'a1'+0, '86trombones' + 0 , '-1.23fourfive' + 0`.  This behavior (strings converted to numeric values) is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the comparision, MySQL converts the string `a` into a number which results in  `0`

The resulting query is

```
select cost from materials WHERE cost > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The decimal column does not contain a letter.  Instead, you are comparing a decimal value to a string.

What does MySQL do with such mixed comparisons?  It converts the values to a compatible type.  In this case, the type is numeric.  So, `'a'` is converted to a number.

What number?  MySQL converts strings to numbers using leading "number-like" characters (digits, decimal point, and negative sign).  `'a'` is not "number-like", so nothing gets converted.  The value is `0`.  So, your comparison is equivalent to:

```
where cost > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I force myql to not convert string?

Comment: @PaoloRossi . . . Aa opposed to converting to an int.  I don't see the utiliitu